# Tkinter error UnboundLocalError: local variable 'flag' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to build quiz using tkinter and python 2

I am having trouble with maintaining score. The validate button can be pressed multiple times which increments global score counter. 1) I've one flag variable which will allow to answer only once and increment global counter only once. Is it possible to disable validate button for correctly answered question? But I'm getting error with it.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1489, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "testtest.py", line 22, in validate
    if(q=="4" and flag==0):
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'flag' referenced before assignment
```

**I read other answers for this problem** but if I pass arguments to validate function it gives error.

2)Is there any way to implement quiz as it will display 1st question and if answer is correct button event will direct to 2nd question unlike my code. It displays all the questions
My code is:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkMessageBox
count=0

class Question(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    def show(self):
            self.lift()

class Question1(Question):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            Question.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
            label = tk.Label(self, text="Question 1: What is 2^2")
            label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
            entry = tk.Entry(self)
            entry.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
            def validate( event ):
                q=entry.get()

                if(q=="4" and flag==0):
                    tkMessageBox.showinfo('Correct Answer', 'Proceed to next question')
                    global count
                    count=count+1
                    fp=open("scores.txt","a")
                    fp.write("\nScore after Question 1 :%d "%(count)) 
                    flag=1
                else:
                    tkMessageBox.showinfo('Wrong Answer', 'Try Again')
                    #flag=0  to avoid alternate event 

            button_1 = tk.Button(self, text="Validate")
            flag=0
            button_1.bind("<Button-1>", validate)

            button_1.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

class Question2(Question):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            Question.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
            label = tk.Label(self, text="Question 1: What is 2^3")
            label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
            entry = tk.Entry(self)
            entry.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

            def validate( event ):
                q=entry.get()

                if(q=="8" and flag==0):

                    tkMessageBox.showinfo('Correct Answer', 'Proceed to next question')
                    global count

                    count=0
                    count=count+1


                    fp=open("scores.txt","a")
                    fp.write("\nScore after Question 2 :%d "%(count)) 
                    flag=1


                else:
                    tkMessageBox.showinfo('Wrong Answer', 'Try Again')

            button_1 = tk.Button(self, text="Validate")
            flag=0
            button_1.bind("<Button-1>", validate)
            button_1.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)


class MainView(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
            p1 = Question1(self)
            p2 = Question2(self)

            buttonframe = tk.Frame(self)
            container = tk.Frame(self)
            buttonframe.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=False)
            container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

            p1.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
            p2.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)


            b1 = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Question 1", command=p1.lift)
            b2 = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Question 2", command=p2.lift)


            b1.pack(side="left")
            b2.pack(side="left")


            p1.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    main = MainView(root)
    main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.wm_geometry("1080x720")
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: In Python indentation is crucial - it's a part of the syntax. Please indent your code properly (standard is 4 spaces per code block)  to let us analyze your code properly.

Comment: @Rogalski  is it okay now? I messed up while copying code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assign to a name in a function, it becomes a local name, even if the function is nested in another function's scope that provides a definition. In Python 3, you could explicitly declare `nonlocal flag` at the top of your `validate` function to make it operate on `flag` from the nested scope, but in Python 2, you can't; Python 2 only has `global` for this purpose, which would skip the nested scope and look for `flag` at the top level scope of the module; usually a bad idea for cases like this.

One approach is to use a `list` so you're assigning to an index, rather than overwriting a local name.

```
class Question1(Question):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Question.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Question 1: What is 2^2")
        label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        entry = tk.Entry(self)
        entry.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        flag = [0]  # Use list over plain int so you can index
        def validate( event ):
            q=entry.get()

            if q == "4" and not flag[0]:  # Test index of list
                tkMessageBox.showinfo('Correct Answer', 'Proceed to next question')
                global count
                count=count+1
                with open("scores.txt","a") as fp:
                    fp.write("\nScore after Question 1 :%d "%(count)) 
                flag[0] = 1  # Assign to index of list
            else:
                tkMessageBox.showinfo('Wrong Answer', 'Try Again')
                flag[0] = 0  # Assign to index of list

        button_1 = tk.Button(self, text="Validate")
        button_1.bind("<Button-1>", validate)

        button_1.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
```

You'd need to make similar edits to `Question2` as well.

Note: I also changed you to using a `with` statement for the file manipulation, so the file is closed and the data is written to disk at a predictable time.

Comment: Is it is possible to disable validate button after correct answer?

Comment: @PariTosh: I'm sure it is, though that's getting way off-topic for your question. Presumably you'd use a call like `button_1.unbind`; I don't know `Tk` off the top of my head, but most event driven languages that provide a `bind` also provide an `unbind`, `detach` or similar method.

Comment: I'm getting this error: 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  
File "testtest.py", line 100, in <module>
    main = MainView(root)
  File "testtest.py", line 76, in __init__
    p1 = Question1(self)
  File "testtest.py", line 33, in __init__
    flag[0]=0
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Comment: @PariTosh: Yup, [looks like there is an `unbind`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html).

Comment: @PariTosh: I believe you made a mistake in the copy and paste then. Are you sure you declared `flag` as `[0]` not `[]`? It clearly became a `list`, and it should have one element; if it doesn't, you did something odd.

Comment: Is it necessary to declare flag global as flag=list()? I'm using flag[0] everywhere. If not it gives error NameError: global name 'flag' is not defined

Comment: @PariTosh: No. Read the actual code I posted. It's declared only in the outer function, as `flag = [0]`, a one-element `list` containing `0`. The only reason for doing this is to allow you to mutate that single element in the `list`, so you bypass name _creation_ in the nested function. You may need to declare `flag` prior to the nested function, but I wouldn't think so. I'll edit to do that just for cleanliness though.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ShadowRanger . My mistake.

Comment: this is working but in alternate manner. Its allowing to increment global counter on odd clicks

Comment: @PariTosh: That's a program logic flaw. We're really off the original question topic now; you need to try to figure that out (hint: `unbind`ing seems like the correct thing to do here, or change your tests so "already gave a right answer" never goes back to "unanswered or wrong answer" state), and ask a new question if you can't.